# Find duplicate XML data depending of a specific attribute using Bash

Tags: xml, bash, duplicates

Is it possible to extract all Xml values depending of a specific XML attribute :
For example i need to take all mobiles who do have the same auth_username ( the first and the last mobile do have the same auth_username

```
    <Fund>
    <mobile>
    <auth_username>736994</auth_username>
    <client_name>736994_iPad</client_name>
    <first_name>Yamelin</first_name>
    <last_name>test</last_name>
    </mobile>
    <mobile>
    <auth_username>735139</auth_username>
    <client_name>735139_iPad</client_name>
    <first_name>Eunbi</first_name>
    <last_name>Eunbi</last_name>
    </mobile>
    <mobile>
    <auth_username>733279</auth_username>
    <client_name>733279_iPad</client_name>
    <first_name>wang</first_name>
    <last_name>test</last_name>
    </mobile>
    <mobile>
    <auth_username>737618</auth_username>
    <client_name>737618_iPad</client_name>
    <first_name>test</first_name>
    <last_name>testLast</last_name>
    </mobile>
    <mobile>
    <auth_username>736994</auth_username>
    <client_name>734131_iPad</client_name>
    <first_name>Kai</first_name>
    <last_name>test</last_name>
    </mobile>
    </Fund>
```

the desired output must be like :

```
    <Fund>
    <mobile>
    <auth_username>736994</auth_username>
    <client_name>736994_iPad</client_name>
    <first_name>Yamelin</first_name>
    <last_name>test</last_name>
    </mobile>
    <mobile>
    <auth_username>736994</auth_username>
    <client_name>734131_iPad</client_name>
    <first_name>Kai</first_name>
    <last_name>test</last_name>
    </mobile>
    </Fund>
```

I tried with xmlstarlet but i just have the auth_username as output

DataFund=$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "Fund/mobile" -n -v "auth_username" ~/Desktop/DeviceAndUserFund2.csv | sort | uniq -d)

is this another way to do ?

Comment: Bash is the wrong tool. Don't screw with a hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash features by themselves are not very well suited to your type of XML requirement. However, here are a couple of solutions which both utilize an [XSLT stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT).

#### Solution 1 - using *xmlstarlet*:

1. Firstly save the following `.xsl`. Let's name the file `get-dupes.xsl`

   **get-dupes.xsl**

   ```xml
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:key name="duplicates" match="mobile" use="auth_username"/>

     <xsl:template match="/Fund">
       <xsl:element name="{name(/*)}">
         <xsl:copy-of select="mobile[count(key('duplicates', auth_username)) > 1]"/>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
2. Then run the following *xmlstarlet* command via your CLI:

   ```
   xml tr /path/to/get-dupes.xsl /path/to/input.xml
   ```

   *Note the `/path/to/` parts in the command above should be changed to the real path to the actual files.*
3. The resultant xml will contain all `<mobile>..</mobile>` elements which have the same `<auth_username>` value.

**Further notes:**

- If you want to omit the xml declaration, (i.e. `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, you can add the `--omit-decl` option to the command. For example:

  ```
  xml tr --omit-decl /path/to/get-dupes.xsl /path/to/input.xml
  ```
- Your source xml data can also be piped to the `xml tr` command if preferred. For instance:

  ```
  cat /path/to/input.xml | xml tr /path/to/get-dupes.xsl
  ```
- To assign the resultant XML to a variable named `DataFund`, you can do this:

  ```
  DataFund="$(xml tr /path/to/get-dupes.xsl /path/to/input.xml)"
  ```
- To save the resultant XML to a new file, you can utilize redirection (`>`) as per the following example:

  ```
  xml tr /path/to/get-dupes.xsl /path/to/input.xml > path/to/output.xml
  ```
- Further information regarding the `xml tr` command and the options available can be found [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139602800).

  The general usage for the `xml tr` command is:

  > `xml tr [<options>] <xsl-file> {-p|-s <name>=<value>} [ <xml-file-or-uri> ... ]`

---

#### Solution 2 - using *xsltproc*:

You can also achieve this with [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html), (which is pre-installed on macOS).

Using the same XSLT stylesheet named `get_dupes.xsl` (shown above) you can:

1. Read the source XML from a file by running the following command:

   ```
   xsltproc /path/to/get-dupes.xsl /path/to/input.xml
   ```
2. Or, pipe the source XML to `xsltproc`. For instance:

   ```
   cat input.xml | xsltproc /path/to/get-dupes.xsl -
   ```

   *Note the trailing hyphen (`-`) is used above to read the source xml data from standard input.*
3. Or, to assign the resultant XML to a variable named `DataFund`, you can do this:

   ```
   DataFund="$(xsltproc /path/to/get-dupes.xsl /path/to/input.xml)"
   ```
4. *xsltproc* does not have an option to omit the xml declaration. To do this you'll need to change the `omit-xml-declaration="no"` attribute in *get-dupes.xsl* to `omit-xml-declaration="yes"`